# Run a Make pattern rule on all matching files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile which, once simplified, looks like this:

```
%.pdf: %.md
    pandoc $< -o $@
```

How can I create a rule which runs this rule for all the `*.md` file present in the folder?

For instance I would like to be able to add new markdown files `x.md`, `y.md` and `z.md`, and then run

```bash
make pdf
```

... to produce `x.pdf`, `y.pdf` and `z.pdf`, without having change the Makefile or run `make x.pdf y.pdf z.pdf` manually.

At the moment, my workaround is to `touch x.pdf y.pdf z.pdf`, `touch *.md`, and `make *.pdf`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MDS  := $(wildcard *.md)
PDFS := $(patsubst %.md,%.pdf,$(MDS))

.PHONY: pdf clean

pdf: $(PDFS)

%.pdf: %.md
    pandoc $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(PDFS)
```

The `clean` phony target is a bonus.

`pdf` and `clean` must be declared as [phony](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Phony-Targets) because they are not real files. This is done by adding them as prerequisites of the `.PHONY` special target.